# Everytime I try to copy from VSCode (on mac with command + c) my cursor goes into --NORMAL-- mode and my cursor becomes a block cursor, how to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I try to copy something in VSCode on my mac with the commands `command` + `c` the cursor changes from a line to a block and automatically goes into `NORMAL` mode as displayed at the bottom of the window [like this image linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQkgo.png). Whenever I press the button `s` on my mac, it returns to `INSERT` Mode, and the cursor is a line again. I have been trying to resolve this issue for some time, but I am unsure where I could fix this in my settings.

Comment: Do you have installed the `Vim` extension before, or share the software Visual Studio Code with others?

Answer (score 24):

You are in [Vim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) keymaps.

Check `extensions`, you should be able to find `Vim` installed and enabled there. Disable or uninstall this extension if you do not need it.

Comment: This worked for me; I did have to reload after disabling Vim before the behavior ceased. FYI for anybody else who might at first glance think that this solution was faulty.

Comment: Same for me. Weirdly this extension caused the issue. Can't find any reports in their github page